# knockoutjs: Writing unit-test for viewModel

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel with a function that does something on click

```
function viewModel() {
   var.self = this;

   self.printFoo = function() {
        console.log(this);
        ....
   }

   self.fooArray = ko.observableArray( [  "foo", "bar" ]);

}
```

The HTML has a `foreach: fooArray` with each elements having a `click: printFoo` binding to call the function.

How can i write a testcase for `printFoo` with sensible Values for this?

I think i have to extract the ViewModel somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Mock the viewmodel? Then there is nothing left to test. What you should mock are all outside dependency like service calls etc. And test the viewmodel functions.

Comment: No, i want to test that printFoo does the right thing. So mock the caller of printFoo

Comment: I agree with @Anders here what are you really trying to accomplish?  If you want to make sure `this` is the `this` you intended you would have to build out a second application with a DOM and assert that `this` is indeed the `this` from the DOM but at what point do you stop?  How do you know the test DOM is going to function properly?

Comment: Viewmodel test are much more stable than full Dom tests so nothing wrong with that .  To test the Foo function,  just execute and assert it? Use qunit or jasmine etc

Comment: Ah,  if you only want to test the clock minding then you need to do it with the DOM,  but there is no point in that test if you ask me

Comment: I don't want to test the DOM, binding etc. I assume knockoutjs works. I would like to test the code i wrote. And yes to execute the function i need to set "this" to something meaningful. i had hoped to avoid having to build a second application with a DOM.